# Cassandra for timeseries with multiple types of measurements

Tags: database, cassandra, time-series, cassandra-2.0

I'm just starting using Cassandra for storing some timeseries data and I'm following the tutorial from http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/

```
CREATE TABLE temperature (
weatherstation_id text,
event_time timestamp,
temperature text,
PRIMARY KEY (weatherstation_id,event_time)
);
```

I understand how it works when there is a single type of measurement - the temperature in this case. But what if we also have a pressure measurement. What's the table's structure in this case? Is the column for a timestamp split to store both the temperature and the pressure, or are two columns created? In case there are two columns is the performance for splicing queries, for example, affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cassandra, the most efficient queries hit a single partition, and then columns using column keys. The first key in the Primary key is your partition key and all subsequent keys are column keys. The order of the column keys matter. You can specify column keys from "left to right"...i.e. you can specify only the partition key, or the partition key + 1st column key, or the partition key + first column key + 2nd column key.... but you can't specify partition key + 2nd column key (not without a secondary index, but I'll leave that out for now). As such, schema in cassandra is very much driven by your query requirements. If you know you'll be querying by type always (as in temperature readings, or pressure reading, or some other readings, or a combination of types), then the following schema can work:

```
CREATE TABLE readings (weatherstation_id text,
event_type text,
event_time timestamp,
reading_value text,
PRIMARY KEY (weatherstation_id, event_type, event_time)
);
```

You could then use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM readings where weatherstation_id = '12' and event_type='temperature'....
```

That creates a row per reading.

Another option is to have multiple readings per row. In that case, the schema might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE readings (weatherstation_id text,
event_time timestamp,
readings map<string, string>,
PRIMARY KEY (weatherstation_id, event_time)
);
```

Then you could get all the readings for a timestamp in one row. That does mean you can't simply filter to a specific type of reading (i.e. you get all the readings for a row), although you could add an index on the key of the map which would let you filter. Check out http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_index_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_eqm_nmd_xj__CreatIdxCollKey for more details. Note that indexing on keys is a new feature of Cassandra 2.1.

Hope that helps.